# Approximate estimate of size of table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

For an administrative procedure I need to estimate the size of a table in our Oracle DB. I know I will have about **5 million rows** of the following data types:

- Varchar2 (3)
- Varchar2 (3)
- Varchar2 (10)
- Varchar2 (40)
- DATE
- DATE

There are no indexes of any kind, there is no PK constraint defined on the table. Assume all values are not nullable.

I do not currently have access to the data, nor can I consult someone who does in time for the procedures deadline.

The estimation does not have to be precise.

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Thought this might be helpful for you to determine what you need. https://workwiththebest.intraway.com/blog-post/estimating-a-schematable-size-in-oracle/

Comment: I have 4 tables in my database around that size (5-6M rows, few columns, all small) and they're 200-300 MB. But exact numbers depend on your database settings as well as your specific dataset.